# Creating a mysql trigger without hard-coding database name

Tags: mysql, trigger

Is there a way to create a trigger in mysql without hardcoding the database name?

Doing a typical create trigger will stop working if I dump the database and then import it into a database of a different name.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll guess an answer to my question. A lot of mysql documentation just references a table name without specifying a database, so I am assuming the database is optional and if you don't include it, mysql will use the current one.

Comment: This is the default behavior on most database systems I've encountered: "If the database name / schema namespace is not specified, assume the current one."

Answer (score 0):

If you mysqldump a table with

```
mysqldump --triggers ...
```

the code for the trigger definition is included.

However, there is a hardcoding situation you want to be cognizant of

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

  insert into outsidedb.audir_trail values (...);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you mysqldump `mytable` and import it into another DB Server, the trigger works only *if and only if* the database `outsidedb` exists on the new DB Server and has the table called `audit_trail`.

Therefore, please keep aware of all hardcoding situations inside and outside of your triggers.